# Keeping two 3D Views in sync?

Tags: 3d-view

I have two 3D views, one for each of my monitors. The first view with a solid shading and the second with the rendered view of Octane render.

It would be great if when rotating my solid shaded view the rendered view would update, on the other monitor, to reflect the same change.

Is this possible with Blender?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that this is unachievable via any internal or scripting means. You can pull down the info window (top bar) and see that only operations are reported, not view motions.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to respond Dr. Who

Comment: Hi, just realized that if you are on Camera view for both monitors then a change to one 3D view would propagate to the other 3D view.
This is closed enough for me. Many thanks for the prompt response!

Answer (score 3):

One way to get any number of 3D views to copy the view angle from one is to have all the 3D views in *Camera* view <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>. Then check "*Lock Camera To View*" in the "*View*" section of the properties region <kbd>N</kbd>.

The downside to this approach is that you always have to stay in the camera view, you can not use any of the view navigation controls. However you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while panning the view to snap the view at 45° angles.

The 3D view on the left is the view copying the center's view. The center is where I'm rotation the view, and where *Lock Camera To View* is checked. The 3D view on the right is just to show what is happening in the scene.
[image: animated gif]