# How to have a live render view

Tags: rendering

I have attach and image below. With the default blender layout i have added an extra window of 3d View. Im having problem i have to check always how it look in render view by pressing shift+z so i created a extra window so that i can have a live render view there but it has same problem i have to go in the that window and press shift+z. Can we have a live render view when i rotate the side window also rotate with the rendering. I have seen in sensei addon it has a small live render window at below. Sensei addon [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrLCBHsNgHw&list=PLS24VPXMziw2bmTkMdgd0crwU2vYH5Bzu&index=12). Any suggestion. I do not want the camera to follow. With lock camera view in N panel. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping two 3D Views in sync?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35157/keeping-two-3d-views-in-sync)

Comment: @p2or Its following the camera but i want to have a live render view.

Comment: just change your [viewport shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html) to rendered in the small window.

Comment: @David can you make it clear plz step by step. I want to have the same result the sensei addon have it. Thanks

Comment: @David imho he wants the little 3d view to always have the same "user persp" as the big main 3d view, so he can edit whatever in the big view, change interactively the view, zoom etc, and the little window will always show the same identical view but in rendered mode. Interesting, but maybe not possible now, without scripting at least...

Comment: @m.ardito As in the sensei addon show the small window with the render view same i need but i do not want to use that addon reason its shortcut or keys are different. Plz go through the video link given above. Thanks

Comment: @ateks can you clarify then what " when i rotate the side window also rotate with the rendering." means? In the video it works differently, imho... look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrLCBHsNgHw&t=20 main view and size view are _not_ showing the same view...

Comment: @m.ardito yeah it works differently but i want the big window preview in a small window with the render view.